# Is my wood cabinet exposing asbestos?

Tags: wood, adhesive, construction, asbestos

My house was built in 1965. We are renters and The side of my wood kitchen cabinet had the top level veneer pulled off. Exposing what’s underneath and possible asbestos glue. We brush past this area constantly and my dog is always wagging her tail into it. Is it possible that we are releasing fibers?

[image]

Comment: The only way to know for certain is to have it tested by a local company. Nobody can guess based on a picture.

Comment: You're renting. Ask the landlord to fix the cabinet.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible that we are releasing fibers?

Anything is *possible*, but it is **highly unlikely** that incidental contact would release fibers. It is also **highly unlikely** that there is any appreciable amount of asbestos there (if any *at all*).

There is a **ZERO** percent chance, assuming there is asbestos there, that the scenario you are describing would in any way release enough asbestos fibers for you to worry about a health concern.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to say from a photo> You could test it or alternatively cover it with vinyl contact paper with a wood grain pattern that matches.